# I have a particle system set to render as collection, only rendering one object

Tags: modeling

I have a few different sprinkle particle systems for the donut tutorial because I was trying different things. The one in question contains different sized long sprinkles and the big round candies. No other system contains those objects. I have it set to render the collection and have weights for different sprinkles. The big round candies are the last object in the collection and have the smallest weight by far. In editor in render view it looks exactly how I want it to in terms of particle distribution, but when I render it for real it looks like it's making all 1000 particles be the large blue candy as if it was set to render as object. What could be going wrong?

Here is what I see in editor in render view:
[image]
Here is what I see when I actually render it using cyles:

[image]

Here are some particle system settings:

[image]

The 60 there refers to the longest bendy sprinkles. TO be sure if I turn off the other particle systems (which handled the tiny spherical rainbow sprinkles and the flat circle candles) this still occurs.

Comment: How many particles are you using in total? (Emission > Number) Also, under "Viewport Display", what is the "Amount" set to?

Comment: 1000 for that group.

Comment: Can you share your .blend file? (Edit your question and use: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

I hid some of the base/reference objects from render so they wouldn't show up in the scene and it seems that was causing issue. I thought it didn't apply to the instances in the particle system. I also had a few other things that were set up slightly oddly I had to redo but I think I'm good now!